# Jquery tabs control - how to select tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following html to show tabs control of jquery:

```
<div id="tabs" class="news1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Track</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">History</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="tabs-1">
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-2">
   </div>
</div>
```

On page load, following script is written:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
```

On page load, tab-1 is selected by default. How can I Programmatically select tab-2 using JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) option, which must be set to the zero-based index of the tab you want to activate:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    active: 1
});
```

Comment: Thanks, was about to ask this! Glad SO has the suggested questions feature ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("selector").tabs("option", {
    "selected": 1,
    "disabled": [0]
});​
```